# How to get TimeStamp of file from MediaStore on Android Q

Tags: android, file, timestamp, mediastore

Please.
In **Android Q,** How to find out **timestamp** of file from **MediaStore** or from mediaUri.

cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)

Not working in Android Q.

Michal

Comment: what about MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_TAKEN

Comment: column 'datetaken' does not exist. Available columns: [_id, _display_name, _size]

Comment: DATE_MODIFIED can be used on Android Q too. Please give an exact code example where it fails.

Comment: I am sorry of this my ask :) it works you are right.
I had an error in the second parameter of the getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query() function not defined colums Date.. of projection.. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code -

```
cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED))
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need a timestamp best as long  type, uri of file or uri of image i can find out.

Comment: I have updated the answer.Can you share the output what you got after this?

Comment: `but i need a timestamp best as long type,` ????     long modified = cursor.getLong(column_modified);

Comment: I am sorry of this my ask :) it works you are right.
I had an error in the second parameter of the getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query() function not defined colums Date.. of projection.. thank you very much.